# pyqtgraph's GraphicsWidgetAnchor class incomplatible with PySide6

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, pyside6

I've written an application that uses **PySide6** and **pyqtgraph**. Now, I upgraded all my Python packages (*PySide 6.5.0* and *pyqtgraph 0.13.2*, *Python 3.10*) and that code crashes.
I was wondering what changed since that and apparently, the following line seems to be the problem:

```py
self.scope_original = pg.PlotWidget(title="Scope")
```

which leads to the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\--\testings\test_pyqtgraph.py", line 15, in <module>
    plot = pg.PlotWidget()
  File "C:\--\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\widgets\PlotWidget.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.plotItem = PlotItem(**kargs)
  File "C:\--\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotItem\PlotItem.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.titleLabel = LabelItem('', size='11pt', parent=self)
  File "C:\--\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\LabelItem.py", line 19, in __init__
    GraphicsWidget.__init__(self, parent)
  File "C:\--\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsWidget.py", line 18, in __init__
    QtWidgets.QGraphicsWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: GraphicsWidgetAnchor.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Is there a workaround that allows me to use PySide6 and pyqtgraph?

---

### Note/Working example:

To check that nothing has changed in pyqtgraph and the problem is indeed PySide6 and not my application, I verifyed the behavior with the [pyqtgraph crash course](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/qtcrashcourse.html) code sample, where I just replaced `PyQt6` with PySide6:

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets  # Should work with PyQt5 / PySide2 / PySide6 as well
import pyqtgraph as pg

## Always start by initializing Qt (only once per application)
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

## Define a top-level widget to hold everything
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
w.setWindowTitle('PyQtGraph example')

## Create some widgets to be placed inside
btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('press me')
text = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('enter text')
listw = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
plot = pg.PlotWidget()

## Create a grid layout to manage the widgets size and position
layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
w.setLayout(layout)

## Add widgets to the layout in their proper positions
layout.addWidget(btn, 0, 0)  # button goes in upper-left
layout.addWidget(text, 1, 0)  # text edit goes in middle-left
layout.addWidget(listw, 2, 0)  # list widget goes in bottom-left
layout.addWidget(plot, 0, 1, 3, 1)  # plot goes on right side, spanning 3 rows
## Display the widget as a new window
w.show()

## Start the Qt event loop
app.exec()  # or app.exec_() for PyQt5 / PySide2
```

which again leads to the same error message above. **PyQt6 works without a problem.** I also can't just easily change PySide6 to PyQt6, due to the scale of the project.

Comment: What OS are you using? I noticed my app using PySide6 and pyqtgraph works fine on Windows, but has this issue on Linux.

Comment: Is a known and [already fixed bug](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/pull/2662) in pyqtgraph, see if you can update it (I don't know how you installed it) or just edit the related files as per the [patch](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/commit/a2557b897342c833f4173e9d0d678f5803e26eed) for that commit.

Comment: That's great. Seems like this patch hasn't been released in a stable version yet so naive `pip install` doesn't work.

Comment: Confirmed installing from git fixes this: `pip install git+https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph@master`. I'll do this until the next stable release